# Gitlab Continuous Integration npm Background Process

Tags: npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a setup of gitlab ci where I want to start a local npm server for testing in the background. My `.gitlab-ci.yml` is like:

```
stages:
  - setup
  - build
  - test

cache:
  paths:
    - venv/
    - node_modules/

setup_nvm:
  stage: setup
  script:
    - "echo installing npm and phantomJS via nvm"
    - "git clone https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git ~/.nvm && cd ~/.nvm && git checkout `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`"
    - ". ~/.nvm/nvm.sh"
    - "nvm install 5.0"
    - "nvm use 5.0"
    - "npm install"
    - "nohup npm run dev &" # HERE I TRY TO RUN THE SERVER IN THE BACKGROUND

setup_python:
  stage: setup
  script:
    - "echo installing python dependencies in virtual environment"
    - "[ ! -d venv ] && virtualenv -p python3 venv"
    - "source venv/bin/activate"
    - "pip3 install -r requirements.txt"

build_multilang:
  stage: build
  script:
    - "[ ! -d tu9onlinekurstest ] && make -f tools/makefiles/multilang"

do_tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - "cd src/test"
    - "python -m unittest"
```

However the job halts and `setup_python` is never started and in status `pending` forever. I thought that jobs would be executed in parallel (according to gitlab runner docs). Do you have experience in running background tasks with gitlab runner?

Comment: Jobs are not designed for this, take a look at [`services`](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#how-to-use-other-images-as-services)

Comment: @mgansler Looks like the asker is not using docker. So `services` would not solve the problem.

Comment: My use case would be launching a web service in a background process and testing it using selenium tests and having the runner shutdown with the service when the tests are done. 
I simple proof of concept would be launching a php simple server process in a background process and pinging it or curling until the page is ready or max time out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [Tomasz Maczukin](https://gitlab.com/tmaczukin) on [a related GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/2231):

> I think the best solution would be to use some service manager
>   (systemd, runit, upstart, sysv - whatever is present on this system).
>
> On the server you should prepare configuration file to start the
>   service. Then in CI job you would do e.g. `systemctl start tomcat`. This
>   command is expected to exit just after calling and it's service
>   manager (outside of Runner's scope) who starts the process.
>
> Process started with Runner, even if you add `nohup` and `&` at the end, is marked with process group ID. When job is finished Runner is
>   sending kill signal to whole process group. So any process started
>   directly from CI job will be terminated at job end. Using service
>   manager you're not starting the process in context of Runner's job.
>   Your only notifying a manager to start a process using prepared
>   configuration :)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I understand that it doesn't explain why the runner hangs in this case and neither does the ticket - but a downvote without a comment seems unnecessary.

Comment: I can confirm that setting up a service and using e.g. systemctl instead works as expected. So +1 from me. (Would still want to know why the build hangs on this, but setting up a service rather than running with `&` to push it in the background looks much more sensible in any case.)

Comment: @steinar the reason why runner hangs is that its first job "setup_nvm" does not exit, even though it's executed with "nohup .. &", the gitlab runner is still 
 monitering it by process group.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example of running a process in the background using the systemd service manager.

In this example, Gitlab CI/CD will deploy a React web app in an HTTP server running on Ubuntu.

#### Step 1: On the runner, create a service unit file

`vi /etc/systemd/system/hello-react.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Hello React service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=gitlab-runner
ExecStart=npx http-server -p 3000 /home/gitlab-runner/hello-react/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### Step 2: On the runner, grant the `sudo` permission to user `gitlab-runner` with no password restriction.

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G sudo gitlab-runner
$ sudo visudo
```

Now add the following line to the bottom of the file

```
gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

#### Step 3: In your code repo, create `deploy.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Build the app for production"
npm run build

echo "Copy over the build"
rm -fr /home/gitlab-runner/hello-react/*
cp -r build/* /home/gitlab-runner/hello-react/

echo "Running server in the background"
sudo systemctl restart hello-react

echo "HTTP server started."
```

#### Step 4: In your code repo, update `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: node:latest

stages:
    - build
    - test
    - deploy

cache:
    paths:
        - node_modules/

install_dependecies:
    stage: build
    script:
        - npm install

    artifacts:
        paths:
            - node_modules/
run_unit_tests:
    stage: test
    script:
        - npm test

deploy_app:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - bash -c './deploy.sh'
```

That's it. The CI/CD job will finish without halting. The app will be deployed, and you can visit it at http://your-server-ip:3000