# How can I run background tasks in Gitlab CICD?

Tags: php, laravel, gitlab

How can I run a service-based command after the build process in gitlab-ci.yml?

For example, i'd like to run:

```
php artisan queue:listen --timeout=0 &
```

The issue is the build runs perpetually and does not finish as it waits for the results of this command (even though this command never finishes).

Is there anyway I can run it as a background task? I tried nohup with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45821533/6309):

> Process started with Runner, even if you add `nohup` and `&` at the end, is marked with process group ID.
> When the job is finished, the Runner is sending a kill signal to the *whole* process group.
> So any process started directly from CI job will be terminated at job end.

Using a systemd service (as in this [same page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56442623/6309)) remains an option, if you control the target server.

Answer (score 2):

With VonC's help - this is the approach I took.

I use Alpine Linux so slightly different to the link he provided, but same approach.

I created a file in `/etc/init.d` and gave it `chmod +x` permissions.

With the following contents:

```
#!/sbin/openrc-run

command="php /var/www/artisan queue:listen"
command_args="--timeout=0"
command_background=true
pidfile="/run/${RC_SVCNAME}.pid"
```

I then ran it with `rc-service laravel-queue start` within the gitlab-ci configuration file.