# gitlab pipeline build hanging due to docker-compose --follow

Tags: docker, gitlab

My gitlab pipeline job includes a bash shell script with various commands. I have my .gitlab-ci.yml pointing to the script. The script deploys some docker containers.

For some reason one of the commands in my script (a docker-compose --follow command) causes the gitlab pipeline to hang and never complete. I know this because when I remove that line from the script, the pipeline completes successfully. When I leave it in, the pipeline never completes, but instead times out after 1 hour.

The app does deploy, and in fact the logging works as intended. I.e., the logs are followed and written to the file. But the pipeline itself never completes. Therefore, I'm thinking the command is getting run in the foreground rather than the background.

Here's an example of a command in my .sh file that works (and doesn't hold up the gitlab pipeline):

```
$SSH "mkdir -p $APP_DIR.logs"
```

But when the .sh script gets to this line it causes the gitlab pipeline to hang:

```
$SSH "cd $APP_DIR && docker-compose logs --follow &> ../$APP_DIR.logs/file.log &"
```

What's interesting is when I execute that line from the server terminal itself, it runs in the background. But when it's part of my pipeline shell commands, it causes the build to hang.

Any idea why?

(I also tried adding `nohup` and that didn't help either.)

Comment: What is in `$SSH` and does it violate [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)? Specifically **5. I'm constructing a command based on information that is only known at run time** We also need to know what shell you are using.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks. Good questions. The SSH variable the user and host info to use a private key file for authentication to a remote host. The shell is bash.

Comment: Something like `SSH="ssh you@somehost"` and you have keys generated with `ssh-keygen` for passwordless authentication? If so, that should be fine, but any time you put more than one aspect of any command in a variable quoting (or not quoting) becomes critical. Thus **BashFAQ #50**.

Comment: ok, good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Process started with Runner, even if you add `nohup` and `&` at the end, is marked with process group ID. When job is finished Runner is sending kill signal to whole process group. So any process started directly from CI job will be terminated at job end. Using service manager you're not starting the process in context of Runner's job. Your only notifying a manager to start a process using prepared configuration :)

Reference: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2231

This is a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56442623/1446609